# How to add an image and some more text to a group description?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, grouping

How do I add an image to the group description, and add some more text next to it?

Here is what I have right now :

[image]

I want the logos to be beside the description, and want some different text at the blue marks like "5x108" for the Ferrari and  "5x114.3" for Dodge. But that is stored next to it in the table

I have all my data stored inside ms sql, and here is how I retrieve it :

```
string connStrings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sql"];
    string Data = @"Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmål, P.Centerhul, P.ET,P.Bolter, P.Dæk, P.Fælge from Data.Hjuldata P  inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID ORDER BY ps.Mærket";
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindData();

    ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(hjuldata.ItemsSource);
    dataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Mærke"));
}

private void BindData()
{
    hjuldata.Items.Clear();
    hjuldata.ItemsSource = kategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;
}

public DataSet kategori()
{
    //SQL statement to fetch entries from data
    DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

    //Open SQL Connection
    using (SqlConnection conns = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
    {
        conns.Open();

        //Initialize command object
        using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(Data, conns))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmds);

            //Fill the result set
            adapters.Fill(dsdata);
        }
    }

    return dsdata;
}
```

What I am trying in XAML

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Expander IsExpanded="False"  BorderBrush="#FFEAEAEA" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=logo}" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding text}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

What do I need to do to make my Group Header include some of the detail data? Change my XAML, change my object model, etc.

Comment: I've edited your question to try and fix the lack of code formatting, punctuation, and grammar, but I am still unclear about what your actual question is. Does the code you posted work? And if not, can you clarify what it is you want help with fixing? Perhaps a picture of what it is now, and what you want it to be would be helpful.

Comment: no it dont as i do not know how to bind them there but had updatet it with a picture since i don't know how to describe my question any better

Comment: Thanks, the addition of the image really helps. I think your problem here is that you are trying to put row detail data in the group header. For example, you are grouping by "Dodge", so that data can go in the header easily. However the Logo, Name, and Text are all part of the individual records, and they may be different between each of the "Dodge" rows. If Grouping is not needed here, I would recommend getting rid of the Grouping on the ListBox, and instead overwrite the `ListBoxItem.Template` property to contain your expander and a grid of data.

Comment: actualy grouping is the most important part of this listview cause it will contains over 15.000 car models which will be puttet in to 125 car brands 
i was able to do the text when i worked with enums but that was just by using alot of spaces for the bolt patterns( 4x100 5x100 5x114.3 6x139.7 etc.) i could probaly also do that for this one so adding the logo next to the car brand is not something you can do?

Comment: I would probably rearrange my data models to match how I want to display them. For example, a CarBrandModel might contain Brand, Logo, BoltPattern, and a collection of CarModel, and CarModel would the actual rows with detail data. Alternatively if you wanted to keep the flat data structure you have now, you could change the string `Brand` to a custom object, such as `CarBrandModel` which would contain Name, Logo, and BoltPattern, then apply the grouping on that object. I don't have enough knowledge of cars or what you are doing to really know how your data should look like though.

Comment: A third option if you only wanted the Logo would be to use a Converter to convert the Brand (ie. Dodge) to an Image (the Logo). I'm not sure how that would be used for the Bolt Pattern though, as I'm not sure if that value can be derived from the Brand or not. (Sorry, I don't know a lot about cars so have no idea what a BoltPattern would be)

Comment: and what i trying to achieve is something like this one here http://www.vejle-autogenbrug.dk/auto/wheel_data/

Comment: the second option is actualy what i am looking for so for that i should change P.Billed(logo) ps.Mærket(brand) P.Krydsmål(boltpatern) into the same table or create a class for thoose string or what exactly do you mean with a custom object?

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19222037/302677) is very similar to yours, and may provide you with a solution. It is trying to group by 2 fields instead of 3, however I think the answers posted there would still apply. The OP's answer offers the solution of creating a blank header style for all groupings except the final one, and for the last Group Header you bind to the `.Items` property to access all grouped items. I haven't tested this myself yet though. The other answer is what I was thinking of with #2 above - creating a class to represent all of your grouped data.

Comment: ah using <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding Items}"> bring me one step closer now i can group by images

Answer (score -1, accepted):

and this solved it

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding Items}">
<Image Source="{Binding Path= Billed}" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Mærke}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Krydsmål}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! Just a note though - you may have to change the Source property on your `ItemCount` binding to refer to the parent DataContext... I can't recall if there's an easy TemplatedParent shortcut, or if it would be easier to use an AncestorType binding to get `Expander.DataContext`. You can also change your StackPanel to something like a Grid if you want to add more spacing between the Brand and the BoltPattern :)

Comment: how would you add spacing with the grid haven't actualy worked with grid before

Comment: If you're new to WPF layouts, I would recommend reading [WPF Layouts - A Quick Visual Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start). It should give you a quick overview of what layout controls are available, and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Without DataContext:

```
    <Expander.Header>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding Items[0].logo}" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
       .....
      </StackPanel>
    </Expander.Header>
```